# Meaning of @6 and @15 in - front of date variable names in the input statement

Tags: sas

I wrote the following code :

```
data dummy;
input @6 dt1 ddmmyy8. @15 dt2 ddmmyy10.;
cards;
30-12-16 30-12-2016
;
run;
```

this gives the following NOTE in the LOG :

```
1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 73         data dummy;
 74         input @6 dt1 ddmmyy8. @15 dt2 ddmmyy10.;
 75         cards;

** NOTE: Invalid data for dt1 in line 76 6-13.**
** NOTE: Invalid data for dt2 in line 76 15-24.**
 RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0                     
 76         30-12-16 30-12-2016
 dt1=. dt2=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1
 NOTE: The data set WORK.DUMMY has 1 observations and 2 variables.
```

**QUESTION 1 : ** What is the meaning of @6 and @15 in front of the variable names dt1 and dt2 ?
**QUESTION 2 : ** Why is this code not working? The output shows missing values instead of SAS date.

Comment: What made you code `@6` and `@15` in the first place ? Are you experimenting or following a guide ?

Comment: @Richard yes, I am following an online article to learn the basics of SAS. While learning, I type out the code side by side on my own. So I didn't add the column control pointer at first. When it gave an error, I added them, not knowing what they were. Still the code did not work. But when I copied the code from the article and pasted it with the correct spaces, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember well beacuse i don't use text readres :-): The @ piont of character first positon in row. So your code correctly(I tested it and work fine):

```
data dummy;
format dt1 dt2 yymmdd10.;
input @1 dt1 ddmmyy8. @10 dt2 ddmmyy10.;
cards;
30-12-16 30-12-2016
;
run;
```

Comment: what if I don't want to use column pointer ? 
For example : 

`

data dummy;
input id age;
cards;
1 21
;
proc print data=dummy;
run;


`

this works fine. The id and age gets stored properly. 

But if I write this code: 

`
data _null_;
input date1 ddmmyy8. date2 ddmmyy10.;
cards;
30-12-16 30-12-2016
;
run;

`

It reads date1 correctly but not date2. Why is that? 

`
NOTE: Invalid data for date2 in line 76 9-18.

date1=20818 date2=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1

`

Comment: Your question was "what is @?" :-)  The new answer for new question is: 

 data dummy;
 input date1 :ddmmyy8. date2 :ddmmyy10.; 
 cards;
 30-12-16 30-12-2016
 ;
 run;

Comment: haha, yes. Thank you for answering that question! :) Now I know what it means, it got me wondering why they're being used..

Comment: Maybe you have very segmented text or you don't want read every text read from text file or datelines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215798/discussion-between-imnotarobot-and-soumya-pandey).

Answer (score 0):

The @ argument in the `INPUT` statement is a column pointer control.  [From documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n0oaql83drile0n141pdacojq97s.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p10kxp5ghaqig7n1qcmwle2swfox)

> @n
>   moves the pointer to column n.

By coding `@6` and `@15` the columns the data will be parsed from is marked below with `^`

```
RULE:      ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5
76         30-12-16 30-12-2016
                ^^^^^^^^                <-- @6 dt1
                         ^^^^^^^^^^     <-- @15 dt2
```

You are 'pointing' at the wrong columns to read the data.  The proper columns are `@1` and `@10`

Comment: what if I don't want to use column pointer ? For example : ` data dummy; input id age; cards; 1 21 ; proc print data=dummy; run; ` this works fine. The id and age gets stored properly. But if I write this code: ` data null; input date1 ddmmyy8. date2 ddmmyy10.; cards; 30-12-16 30-12-2016 ; run; ` It reads date1 correctly but not date2. Why is that? ` NOTE: Invalid data for date2 in line 76 9-18. date1=20818 date2=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=1 ` –

Comment: The answer for new question: 
 data dummy;
 input date1 :ddmmyy8. date2 :ddmmyy10.; 
 cards;
 30-12-16 30-12-2016
 ;
 run;